# Change displayed view in a UIPopoverView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I'm presenting a UIPopoverView like so:

```
if (self.BStatePopoverViewController == nil) {
        RedStatePopoverViewController *settings =
        [[RedStatePopoverViewController alloc]
         initWithNibName:@"RedState"
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        UIPopoverController *popover =
        [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:settings];

        popover.delegate = self;

        self.BStatePopoverViewController = popover;
    }

    [BStatePopoverViewController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 445)];
    [self.BStatePopoverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Once the view is loaded in the popover, I have a button which I'd like to use to present a new UIViewController within the popover. I tried just presenting it as a modal view but this changes the parent view as opposed to the one in the popover:

```
PopupDischargeViewController * dischargeview = [[PopupDischargeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopupDischargeViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:dischargeview animated:NO];
```

Any help as to how I do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change the view controller the popover should display once it's been initialized use `UIPopoverController`'s method `– setContentViewController:animated:`

You could also add your `RedStatePopoverViewController` to a `UINavigationController` and use its methods `– pushViewController:animated:` and `– popViewControllerAnimated:` to navigate between view controllers

Hope this helps!